# How To Parse Audio Wav File in Tensorflow

Tags: python, parsing, tensorflow

I am new to Python, and want to train an audio model. I converted my audio file to .wav format.

How can i parse those audio **.wav** file into the **tensorflow**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Librosa](http://librosa.github.io/librosa/), it is sound processing library. You can install it by

```
pip install librosa
```

Then,

```
import librosa
import tensorflow as tf

data , sampling_rate = librosa.load('data/sound.wav')
# for use in tensorflow
data_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor( data )
```

Comment: but i need tensorflow,,part of requirenments..so kindly help me out this

Comment: You can convert the numpy array to tensor for using it in tensorflow

Comment: yes i had converted those audio files to .wav file with numpy-array, now struggling to parse into the tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is documented in the link below:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/audio/decode_wav

With

```
tf.audio.decode_wav(
    contents, desired_channels=-1, desired_samples=-1, name=None
)
```

you can decode a 16-bit PCM WAV file to a float tensor. In return, you get a tuple of Tensor objects (audio, sample_rate) where audio   is a tensor of type float32, and sample_rate a tensor of type int32.